# Error: Minified React error #130: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm building an app in reactJS and I have a problem only on PRODUCTION build
(everything is fine on dev)

I identified the problem but can't resolve it, I have a class named 'Dashboard' and a subcomponent in it, and another subcomponent in the subcomponent that make the app raise Error 130.

> Error: Minified React error #130; visit [https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]=](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args%5B%5D=undefined&args%5B%5D=) for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

Here is my code :

```
export class Dashboard extends React.Component {

    loginTextBox = () => {
        return (<div> Hello World</div>)
    }

    connectionPannel = () => {
        return(<div>
            <this.loginTextBox></this.loginTextBox>   /* IF I COMMENT THIS, IT WORKS */
        </div>)
    }


    render() {
        return(<div className="h-100">
            <this.connectionPannel></this.connectionPannel>
        </div>);
    }
}
```

to deploy I use: yarn build and then i used serve -s build or a dedicated server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, this is a babel compilation bug actually. I'd recommend either inlining the JSX or extracting those bits to actual function components:

```
// inline the JSX
export class Dashboard extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="h-100">
                <div>
                  <div>Hello World</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

```
// extract to components

export class Dashboard extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(<div className="h-100">
            <ConnectionPannel />
        </div>);
    }
}

function ConnectionPannel() {
  return (
    <div>
      <LoginTextBox />
    </div>
  )
}

function LoginTextBox() {
  return <div>Hello World</div>
}
```

In that case you'd also need to pass things as props. That's arguably more idiomatic React.

You could *also* invoke the function as shared in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63058882/971592) but there's not really any benefits to that approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the function

```
    connectionPannel = () => {
        return(<div>
            {this.loginTextBox()}
        </div>)
    }
```